# how to get intellisense for methods of modules which are imported from an alias in .vue

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

In .vue and .js, I can enjoy the intellisense of vscode when developing.
But I found it doesn't work any more when I use an alias.
So I have searched for a while on blogs, found a solution, which is to configure a 'jsconfig.json' as below.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

it worked in the .js file but didn't work in .vue file.
Does anyone know how to resolve it ?

**Does work in .js**

[image]

**Not work in .vue**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With vue-cli the alias is defined in the webpack-config (since @vue/cli uses webpack under the hood). So instead of jsconfig.json <strike>(delete it! just do it!)</strike> , I would:

### 1: Install the webpack resolver for eslint:

```
npm i eslint-import-resolver-webpack
```

### 2: Reference the plugin from your `.eslintrc.js`

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": "webpack"
},
```

#### Done!

This is my complete `.eslintrc.js` just to be thorough:

```
module.exports = {
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": "webpack"
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint"
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/recommended"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  rules: {}
}
```

If any issues remains I would check the eslint-settings in vscode `settings.json`:

```
"eslint.enable": true,
"eslint.provideLintTask": true,
"eslint.workingDirectories": ["src"],
"eslint.validate": ["javascript","javascriptreact","vue"],
```

Comment: I have tried as yours,it does work in .vue ,but I find your solution doesn't work in .js. Is that my pose incorrect?

Comment: oops ,I found your solution did resolve my problem,but the jsconfig.json is required or it would not work

Comment: Ah, right you are! My mistake! I tried to remove the `jsconfig.json` and checked my vue-file and it stilled worked but I never even bothered looking at my js-files. Sorry!  So just don't delete the jsconfig and it works in both!

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question,how can i refresh eslint's configuration immediately. just now , it took such a long time to go into effect.

Comment: For me it is immediate! And I think it is as long as there are no errors in your eslintrc (and you need to save of course). But I use vscode's reload window for things that don't refresh automatically (F1, type "REL".. and you'll find it)  I bound a key for it. Mostly because I want want to be sure whether things have propagated or not.

Comment: thanks ,it seems this is the only method to refresh it